# AWS Workspace Crontab only running when user is logged in

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cron

When looking I can only find answers regarding crontab and EC2 instances. We created an AWS Workspace as a lightweight solution for our virtual machines.

Does crontab on the machine work when the user is not logged in? I have an hourly bash script that does not run unless I log into the Workspace.

Comment: Is your workspace in `Always-On` configuration? If not, try setting this option.

Comment: Talked to our DevOps team member and he made this adjustment.. No console access. Thanks!

Comment: Did it fix your issue?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.